# RxJS subscribe to array: see the changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx/store to keep track of an array of active layers (to be shown on a map).

```
{
  layers: ['layer_1', 'layer_2']
}
```

In my component I subscribe to this variable:

```
 this.mapState$
    .map(mapState => mapState.layers)
    .subscribe(layers=> console.log(layers));
```

Current situation

- When adding layer_3 get `['layer_1', 'layer_2', 'layer_3']`
- When removing layer_2 I get `['layer_1', 'layer_3']`

What I try to achieve
Instead of one array with the current situation. I'd like two arrays. One with all additions and one with all removals.

Different approaches are welcome. The key thing is that I want to store it in ngrx/store.

These are just my first steps. In my final app I want to support waypoints, which can be added, removed but also moved. And when moving a waypoint I need to read the waypoint before and after it in the array to manipulate (calculate and redraw) a route.

Update: apparantly there was an Observable.ofArrayChanges for RxJS but it has been deprecated in RxJS 5.

Comment: I found the pairwise operator. But can't get it to work. Besides that I don't think it's suited for initialisation since it only triggers on the 2nd 'tick'.

Comment: I didn't quite get it.  You want to have two stores one tracks additions and other removals ?

Comment: No, I certainly don't want to log my changes in a store. The store should only have the current state.

I just want to know if there is an RxJS operator that shows the differences from the previous to the current state (or just returns them both so I can find out the difference myself).

Comment: then you should have two stores . One temporary, other permanent. Your component will see the difference and perform another action to merge update permanent store . Using operators I dont see its possible

Answer (score 0):

You can approach with this way:

**Reducer:**

```
{
  layers: ['layer_1', 'layer_2'],
  changesInLayer: { type: 'ADD', layers: ['layer_1', 'layer_2']}
}
```

**Action:**

ADD_LAYER:

```
{
   layers: [...this.state.layers, action.payload],
   changesInLayer: { type: 'ADD', layers: [action.payload]}
}
```

REMOVE_LAYER:

```
{
   layers: this.state.layers.filter(item => {
       return item !== action.payload
   }),
   changesInLayer: { type: 'REMOVE', layers: [action.payload]}
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.mapState$
    .subscribe(state => console.log(state.layers, state.changesInLayer));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I'm hoping there is another way so I can keep my application state separated from an event log.